# How are parallel runways named if there are more than 2 or 3?

Tags: airport, runways, airport-design, parallel-runways

I know that it's very common for runways to have a parallel neighbor, and they're normally called left and right. I have also seen some runways called "center" if there are three parallel runways.

What would happen if there were more than that? Is this even possible?

Comment: thanks, sorry about that